# Date formatting with igx-date-picker

Tags: html, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-template

I have an Angular template which implements an IgxDatePickerComponent. I am having an issue trying to format the date to a UK format for both the drop-down part of the control and the input part.

Here is my code for the control

```
 <igx-date-picker  #dateFromDatePicker mode="dropdown" locale="en-GB"
             cancelButtonLabel="close" todayButtonLabel="today">
              <ng-template igxDatePickerTemplate let-openDialog="openDialog" let-value="value"
                  let-displayData="displayData">
                  <igx-input-group type="border">
                      <igx-prefix (click)="openDialog(dropDownTarget)">
                          <igx-icon>today</igx-icon>
                      </igx-prefix>
                      <label igxLabel for="dropDownTarget">Start Date</label>
                    <input #dropDownTarget  class="igx-date-picker__input-date" igxInput [value]="displayData"
                          [igxMask]="'00/00/0000'" [placeholder]="'dd/mm/yyyy'"  (blur)="changeStartDate($event)"/>
                  </igx-input-group>
              </ng-template>
          </igx-date-picker>
```

And the component code is

```
  changeStartDate(event) {
    const input = event.target.value;
    if (input !== '') {
      const parsedDate = new Date(input);
      if (this.isDateValid(parsedDate)) {
        this.startDate = parsedDate;
      }
    } else {
      this.dateFromDatePicker.deselectDate();
      this.startDate = input;
    }
  }
```

When the blur event fires event.target.value is "29/04/2020"
When this hits the following line of code.

```
const parsedDate = new Date(input);
```

The result of parsedDate is "invalid date".

I need to convert "29/04/2020" into a valid date. I've tried various pipes but none seem to work.

Comment: What is the value of `displayData` bound with datepicker? `[value]="displayData"`?

Comment: The value is a UK formatted string date, i.e.  "29/04/2020"

Answer (score 0):

You have to format your `displayDate` string in order to convert it into valid Date

```
        const parsedDate = new Date(input.split('/').reverse().join("-"));
```

This would convert your `"29/04/2020"` to `"2020-04-29"` and then it would be acceptable for `Date`.